TypeError: expected dynamic type `string', but had type `array' on Expo 52
I recently switched to expo SDK 52 but now my code is showing an error that wasn't showing on SDK 51 :
Warning: Error: Exception in HostFunction: TypeError: expected dynamic type `string', but had type `array'

This error is located at:
    in RCTScrollView
    in VScrollViewNativeComponent (created by ScrollView)
    in ScrollView (created by ScrollView)
    in Wrapper
    in CSSInterop.ScrollView (created by Home)
    in RNCSafeAreaView
    in Unknown (created by Home)
    in Home
    ...
    in ExpoRoot (created by App)
    in App (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorToastContainer (created by ErrorOverlay)
    in ErrorOverlay (created by withDevTools(ErrorOverlay))
    in withDevTools(ErrorOverlay)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in RCTView (created by View)
    in View (created by AppContainer)
    in AppContainer
    in main(RootComponent)

I've already tried npx expo install --fix and expo-doctor but nothing has worked for me.
I can't find where the error is coming from either.

Passing an array where a string is required or Invalid child components within the ScrollView

TypeError: expected dynamic type 'array', but had type 'string'" error in a HostFunction
while using react native is it :
This is problem from RichText editor
please remove this property from nodemodules
DataDetectorType={none}
remove this line from nodemodules/react-native-pell-rich-editor/src/RichEditor.js


Hi, thanks for your answer. I don't have this module installed, I think it may come from another one but when I type DataDetectorType={none} in my search it doesn't find anything.
